# C++ regex character class not matching

Tags: c++, regex, character-class

from what i researched, the expression "[:alpha:]" will be matched for any alphabetic character, but the expression only match for lowercase character and not uppercase character. I not sure what's wrong with it.

```
std::regex e ("[:alpha:]");
if(std::regex_match("A",e))
     std::cout<<"hi";
  else
     std::cout<<"no";
```

Comment: "[:digit:]" doesnt work either when i want to match a digit

Comment: Try with `[[:alpha:]]`

Comment: oh yours work! thx

Comment: See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/ :
Please note that the brackets in the class names are additional to those opening and closing the class definition.
For example:
`[[:alpha:]]` is a character class that matches any alphabetic character.
`[abc[:digit:]]` is a character class that matches `a`, `b`, `c`, or a digit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this:

```
std::regex e ("[:alpha:]");
```

to:

```
std::regex e ("[[:alpha:]]");
```

As Adrian stated: Please note that the brackets in the class names are additional to those opening and closing the class definition. For example: `[[:alpha:]]` is a character class that matches any alphabetic character. Read more in the [ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/).

Comment: And what if you want this class in a class? Say `[a-zA-Z.-+/*]`, you write `[[[:alpha]].-+/*]` with 3 opening brackets?

Comment: @Sandburg no: 2 brackets, not 3. And don't forget to escape the hyphen (-). So you write [[:alpha:].\-+/*].

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `[[:alpha:]]`

see [online example](https://ideone.com/de1xKB)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::regex e ("[[:alpha:]]");
if(std::regex_match("A",e))
     std::cout<<"hi";
  else
     std::cout<<"no";
    return 0;
}
```